# React ESLint (react/display-name) Not Working

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, eslintrc

I was wondering if eslint rules for react `(react/display-name)` is working for anyone?

Currently, on my code, it doesn't show any warning if I do not put the `displayName`.
I am expecting if I don't put `displayName` it will throw an eslint warning message.

e.g.

> Component.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const Component = () => {
 return (
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
 );
};

export default Component;
```

> .eslintrc

```
{
 . . .
 "rules": {
  "react/display-name": [2],
 }
 . . .
}
```

I am expecting there should be a lint warn, but nothing came up.

Is there any configuration that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will only show an error if your component doesn't have a name. In your case your component's name is `Component`. This is because react automatically transpiles the name of the component.

If you don't want the name to be [transpiled automatically](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/display-name.md), you need to disable the transpiled Name with `"react/display-name": [2, { "ignoreTranspilerName": true }],`. Then you will get the behavior that you expect.

The rule that you have currently configured will throw an error if your component would look like this:

```js
const Hello = createReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});
module.exports = Hello;
```

Comment: ahhh you are correct! Adding the second parameters to the rules and I get the expected result.
Thanks for the explanation tho :)